# What namespace identifiers are in Boost and Qt libraries?

Tags: c++, qt, boost, namespaces

I've started using boost and Qt recently. I would like to know if all the Boost libraries(headers) are wrapped into one namespace: Boost? Or are there some other namespaces as well?

Same question for Qt, it looks like the Qt libs do not have namespaces at all?
So I've started building Qt with these flags:

> configure -shared -debug-and-release -ltcg -qtnamespace qt nmake

Is that OK?

Comment: The Boost placeholders are defined in an unnamed namespace, so "all the boost libraries" are not in one namespace.  I don't know of any other counterexamples off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Boost libraries generally put their stuff in `boost` namespace or subnamespaces of it. Some *might* define global symbols, but the documentation will tell you if that's the case.

Qt's use of namespaces is very limited. It prefers to prefix all of its symbols with Q or Qt, although it uses `Qt` namespace for some identifiers, and maybe some others.

Answer (score 1):

In general, yes - all of boost declarations are under a global `::boost` namespace.

However, I know of one exception:

The bind-expression placeholders `_1`, `_2` etc are in a global 'anonymous' namespace, and are thus correctly referenced as:

```
boost::bind(&f, ::_1, ::_2);
```

*Note that these placeholders do not have external linkage and are statics (local to the Translation Unit)*

Answer (score 1):

I've used `boost::matrix::ublas` frequently, but boost has many namespaces.  You could run variations of the command inside the particular boost subdirectory about which you care :

```
grep namespace * | sed -e 's/.*namespace//' -e 's/\/\/.*//' -e 's/ *{.*//' | sort | uniq
```

Your question should usually be : What namespaces are appropriate for use in my current project?  I.e. what name spaces look useful but are actually internal boost stuff.

As a rule, users shouldn't need anything inside boost's detail namespaces, but you'll find other namespaces used for implementation details too.  `boost::math::tr1` does nothing but import ordinary C math functions for example.